# Regex to grab formulas

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse a file that contains parameter attributes. The attributes are setup like this:

```
w=(nf*40e-9)*ng
```

but also like this:

```
par_nf=(1) * (ng)
```

The issue is, all of these parameter definitions are on a single line in the source file, and they are separated by spaces. So you might have a situation like this:

```
pd=2.0*(84e-9+(1.0*nf)*40e-9) nf=ng m=1 par=(1) par_nf=(1) * (ng) plorient=0
```

The current algorithm just splits the line on spaces and then for each token, the name is extracted from the LHS of the = and the value from the RHS. My thought is if I can create a Regex match based on spaces within parameter declarations, I can then remove just those spaces before feeding the line to the splitter/parser. I am having a tough time coming up with the appropriate Regex, however. Is it possible to create a regex that matches only spaces within parameter declarations, but ignores the spaces *between* parameter declarations?

Comment: Is it possible to separate the single equations by another character, e.g. a semicolon?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the way the source is supplied to me. Not ideal i know, but it is a Spectre netlist, and if you know anything about semiconductor EDA tools, it's that you're pretty much stuck with what they give you. I am not ruling out an alternative solution, like a pre-processing step for the line, if that helps. I just thought there must be a good way to capture only the spaces within the parameter defs, and I just don't know enough regex to do so.

Comment: What kind of regex are we talking? `sed`? Posix? PCRE? Is it also an option to just split the string on certain regex matches (and later rebuild it)?

Comment: @Siguza My parser is written in perl.

Comment: It hink you should match on the '=' and go backwards to the next space, probably this will do the trick: "\w+[a-zA-Z_]=". When you have such a match, you could insert a linebreak before.

Comment: Excellent call, @Andy. I added a whitespace capturing group before the \w which I will use to replace the preceding whitespace with a delimiting character.

Comment: +1 Good question! I really do like answering questions like these. They require some thinking and logic!

Comment: @Andy I did it the opposite way round, using a negative lookahead to check for `\s\w+=`, and stop the match when it is found

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

```
(?<=^|\s)       # Start of each formula (start of line OR [space])
(?:.*?)         # Attribute Name
=               # =
(?:             # Formula
(?!\s\w+=)        # DO NOT Match [space] Word Characters = (Attr. Name)
[^=]              # Any Character except =
)*              # Formula Characters repeated any number of times
```

When checking formula characters, it uses a negative lookahead to check for a <kbd>Space</kbd>, followed by Word Characters (Attribute Name) and an `=`. If this is found, it will stop the match. The fact that the negative lookahead checks for a space means that it will stop without a trailing space at the end of the formula.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cS3gK5/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andy for the tip:

In this case I'll probably just match on the parameter name and equals, but replace the preceding whitespace with some other "parse-able" character to split on, like so:

```
(\s*)\w+[a-zA-Z_]=
```

Now my first capturing group can be used to insert something like a colon, semicolon, or line-break.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Perl` tag. :-(  Maybe this will help:

---

I ended up using this in C#. The idea was to break it into name value pairs, using a negative lookahead specified as the key to stop a match and start a new one. If this helps

```
var data = @"pd=2.0*(84e-9+(1.0*nf)*40e-9) nf=ng m=1 par=(1) par_nf=(1) * (ng) plorient=0";

var pattern = @"
(?<Key>[a-zA-Z_\s\d]+)           # Key is any alpha, digit and _
=                                # = is a hard anchor
(?<Value>[.*+\-\\\/()\w\s]+)     # Value is any combinations of text with space(s)
(\s|$)                           # Soft anchor of either a \s or EOB
((?!\s[a-zA-Z_\d\s]+\=)|$)       # Negative lookahead to stop matching if a space then key then equal found or EOB
";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => new
     {
         LHS = mt.Groups["Key"].Value,
         RHS = mt.Groups["Value"].Value
     });
```

Results:

[image]